# Java polymorphism pointers

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism

I've been studying java a little bit and I've come upon a problem I couldn't solve (I did research but since it's a pretty specific question no answer was found):

I'm trying to add variables and methods that would be inherited by classes in the same way an interface does it (have a class inherited by different classes that already have an ancestor, i.e.: Actor extends Character and Weapon extends Item, I need both Actor and Weapon to have XY coordinates, width/height and move() method)

At first I thought Interfaces were the solution, but since they are 100% abstract, I would need to redefine the methods every time, which, to me, beats the purpose of inheritance in this case.

I have thought about making a superior parent (like MovableObject) at the root of the ancestry tree which would include both the Item and Actor classes, but since they are so different in every other way it feels counter logic to have them in the same ancestry tree.

### Edit

Thank you all for your responses, I said I'd update when I tried it, and I did but now I realize my whole code is going to need a lot of refactoring so I can't tell you if it works or not right away. Although it did solve my problem since I at least have something to work towards.

Comment: What about using an abstract class?  They can define common methods which actually have an implementation, but they still behave fairly similarly to interfaces.  Maybe include some sample code here.

Comment: Use either an abstract class or if you are using Java 8 or greater, interfaces can have default implementations such that you do not have to override them in your implementing class.

Comment: Make Character and Item child classes of a common abstract class, like what you have mentioned. The key thing to consider is how are all these classes similar. If all characters and items are definitely *movable*, but they can *move* in a different manner, then it makes sense to use the common class, which would keep some portions abstract for subclass to define the details.

Comment: Ok thanks for all the quick answers ! i'm going to try the parent abstract class, i'll update when i see how it works out. (PS: ooh i didnt know interfaces could have default implementation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language constructs that you can use are either *interfaces* or *abstract classes*.

- **Interfaces:** define common behavior across unrelated objects (for example, objects that can be serialized, objects that can be compared, etc).
- **Abstract classes:** define common behavior across a hierarchy of objects (for example, it would make sense to define a method `getPrice` in `Item` and inherit that in `Weapon`).

In your example, methods such `getWidth()`, `getHeight()`, `getX()` and `getY()` are good candidates for interfaces (since they share some common traits between unrelated objects).

```
// Another way to share this state would be via a Point interface and 
// aggregating two point objects in your Item and Character classes
interface Coordinates {

    double getX1();

    double getY1();

    double getX2();

    double getY2();

}

interface Dimension {

    double getWidth();

    double getHeight();

}
```

I don't know your whole context, but are you sure you need both coordinates and dimensions (I think you could determine the width and height from the X and Y)?

Those interfaces should be implemented by both of your ancestor classes (`Character` and `Item`) and inherited through the hierarchy. Do **not** add a common ancestor between `Character` and `Item` just so you can avoid implementing `getX` and `getY` twice.

Regarding the `move` method, I think it's another responsibility and you should define it somewhere else.

```
// Not necessarily the right name
class MoveHelper {

    // You can pass either a Character or an Item here
    // since both implement Coordinates
    // Not necessarily the right signature
    void move (Coordinates object)

}
```

Depending on how you chose to design your solution, the `move` method can become a `static` somewhere or an object that you would aggregate in both `Character` and `Item` and delegate to it for the `move` implementation.

As a final note, consider that you can achieve reuse via either *inheritance* (interfaces and abstract classes) or *composition* (what you would do if you would aggregate the `MoveHelper` and delegate to it for the `move` implementation in `Character` and `Item`).

Hope this helps!